# Merge several dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge

If in this code I merge 2 data frames by ID,

```
full <- merge(data frameA,data frameB,by="ID")
```

How can I merge 4 data frames by the same ID avoiding using this code several times?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst <- list(dfB, dfC, dfD)
result <- dfA
for (df in lst) result <- merge(result,df,by="ID")
```